# If $X$ is a nontrivial random variable, then $\left|\operatorname E\left[e^{{\rm i}Xy_n}\right]\right|<1$ for some $y_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, exponential-function

Let $X$ be a nontrivial real-valued random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$. Why can we find a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb R$ with $$0<\left|\operatorname E\left[e^{{\rm i}Xy_n}\right]\right|<1\tag1\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N$$ and $y_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$?

We've clearly got $$0<\left|\operatorname E\left[e^{{\rm i}Xy_n}\right]\right|\le\operatorname E\left[\left|e^{{\rm i}Xy_n}\right|\right]=1\tag2\;\;\;\text{for all }y\in\mathbb R.$$

Comment: (1) is surely wrong since ch. functins tend to $1$ at $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sure, you're right. Changed it to $<1$. What do you think?

Comment: See Corollary to Theoerm 6.4.7 in Chung's book (A Course in Probability Theory).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You mean the theorem "A ch.f. is that of a lattice distribution if and only if ..."? Why does the claim follow from that? And is there an other argument available? Never heard of the term "lattice distribution" before.